# Keep RelativeLayout height as small as possible, but increase children height to fill all available space

Tags: android, height, android-relativelayout

My RelativeLayout contains few ImageView/TextView controls of different height, e.g. 20, 70, 35. The controls alligned in a row. I want them to expand their height to the same value of the maximum control height, e.g. 70. The problem is that with my layout the RelativeLayout container and all controls expanded to the screen height instead.

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/image1" 
            android:background="#FFCCDDEE"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />

        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/image2" 
            android:background="#FFCCDDEE"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/image3" 
            android:background="#FFCCDDEE"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I can set RelativeLayout height to 70, but consider that I don't know the child controls size upfront.

I also can achieve desired effect with LinearLayout, but want to use the RelativeLayout.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/image1" 
            android:background="#FFCCDDEE"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />

        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/image2" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />

        <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/image3" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you can place the LinearLayout in a RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using padding / margins?

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView 
        android:src="@drawable/image1" 
        android:background="#FFCCDDEE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="70dip"
        />
    ....
```

That XML should produce an image that is 140 x 140 (I think). It won't be dynamic, but the XML isn't able to do dynamic things like that.

If you want to do something that is more dynamic you could write code that would pull all your elements size's, find the largest, then set all of your objects to that size.

This [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#SizePaddingMargins) might be useful for that.

Good luck!