# Let RelativeLayout's childrens fill the screen's height , without pushing off the screen

Tags: android

Basically I 7 of these , with their parent RelativeLayout

```
 <!-- Sunday -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/table_view_sundaylayout"
        android:layout_margin="0.3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Sun"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_table"
            android:layout_margin="0.3dp"
            />

        <com.myapp.app1.Custom_Edit_Text 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Empty.."
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_table"
            android:id="@+id/table_sunday1"
            android:layout_margin="0.3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <com.myapp.app1.Custom_Edit_Text 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Empty.."
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_table"
            android:id="@+id/table_sunday2"
            android:layout_margin="0.3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <com.myapp.app1.Custom_Edit_Text 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Empty.."
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_table"
            android:id="@+id/table_sunday3"
            android:layout_margin="0.3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

        <com.myapp.app1.Custom_Edit_Text 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Empty.."
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_table"
            android:id="@+id/table_sunday4"
            android:layout_margin="0.3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

the problem is I want these layouts to extend and fill the screen no matter what with the same size , now it depends up on the screen for example in the graphical layout the tablet about 50% of the screen is empty only my background is there.

I've solved this using linear layouts but the problem is I had to use nested weights which may be a little slow , I'm noticing it at least.

I've searched and found this:

[Keep RelativeLayout height as small as possible, but increase children height to fill all available space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530750/keep-relativelayout-height-as-small-as-possible-but-increase-children-height-to)

this may be the closest thing to my case , but the padding solution might push elements off the screen sometimes , I don't want that.

Comment: in each of the ui elements change the value of layout_width to that of height and height to width. This will probably solve your problem

Comment: What ? but if I for example put the first edit text width to match parent it'll take the whole width ? or I'm getting the wrong idea here ?